# UWP - Command from DataGrid is not called

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, datagrid, command

UWP Application (Important because there is no AncestorType)
I can't bind command (neither other values) of the ViewModel from a DataGridTemplateColumn.
Here is my current code (i have tried, literally everything)

```
          <controls:DataGrid
            x:Name="DataGrid" 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Height="Auto" 
            Margin="12"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProviderOrders}">
             <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" Width="*">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Modifier" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditOrderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

I have also tried

```
<Button Content="Modifier" Command="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=DataContext.EditOrderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
```

There is no error but my Command is not runned and my command is working if i move the Button outside the DataGrid..

The DataGridTemplateColumn DataContext is the ProviderOrder object and so i need to access of the ViewModel (which is obviously not accessible from the ProviderOrder object)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Great question, this known issue in `DataGrid` control. Currently, there is a workaroung for this scenario that bind command for button in `CellTemplate`, please add the command in the datasouce.

```
public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public ICommand BtnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommadEventHandler<Item>((s) => BtnClick(s));
        }
    }

    private void BtnClick(Item s)
    {

    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button
                Command="{Binding BtnCommand}"
                Content="Click"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Update**

If not specific `DataGrid`, you could use listview to replace, and `Binding ElementName` will work.

Comment: Mmh, Is there any workaround less "dirty", just keeping the Command in the ViewModel would be great .. Or i will just remove the DataGrid  and use a simple ListView with Grids. That DataGrid is quite useless actually .. Thanks for ur answer btw

Comment: If not specific `DataGrid`, you could use listview to replace, and `Binding ElementName` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue where the button command was not invoked.

Workaround Solution :

1. Create a attached property to find the parent element based on type.
2. Use the attached property in the button and specify the type as Datagrid.
3. Boom! command will be invoked.

AttachedProperties :

> ```
> public static class AncestorSource
> {
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AncestorType", typeof(Type), typeof(AncestorSource), new PropertyMetadata(default(Type), OnAncestorTypeChanged));
>
>     public static void SetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element, Type value) => element.SetValue(AncestorTypeProperty, value);
>
>     public static Type GetAncestorType(FrameworkElement element) => (Type)element.GetValue(AncestorTypeProperty);
>
>     private static void OnAncestorTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)d;
>         if (target.IsLoaded)
>         {
>             SetDataContext(target);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             target.Loaded += OnTargetLoaded;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static void OnTargetLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
>         target.Loaded -= OnTargetLoaded;
>         SetDataContext(target);
>     }
>
>     private static void SetDataContext(FrameworkElement target)
>     {
>         Type ancestorType = GetAncestorType(target);
>         if (ancestorType != null)
>         {
>             target.DataContext = FindParent(target, ancestorType);
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static object FindParent(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Type ancestorType)
>     {
>         DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
>         if (parent == null)
>         {
>             return null;
>         }
>
>         if (ancestorType.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()))
>         {
>             return parent;
>         }
>
>         return FindParent(parent, ancestorType);
>     }
> }
> ```

In Xaml,

1. Add namespace for the attached property

> xmlns:ansestorSource="using:Win.Ui.Controls.AttachedProperties"

2. Your DataGridTemplateColumn should be :

> ```
> <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
>     <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actions" Width="*">
>         <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
>             <DataTemplate>
>               <Grid x:Name="Parent_Grid">
>                   <Button Content="Modifier" 
>                           ansestorSource:AncestorType="controls:DataGrid"
>                           Command="{Binding DataContext.EditOrderCommand}" 
>                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName="Parent_Grid", Path="DataContext"}" 
>                           Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}"/>
>               </Grid>
>             </DataTemplate>
>         </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
>     </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
> </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
> ```