# UWP ButtonColumn MvvmLight / Telerik / WindowsTemplate Studio

Tags: c#, telerik, uwp-xaml, windows-template-studio

I´m trying to add a ButtonColumn to a TelerikDataGrid which was generated by the Windows Template Studio, without CodeBehind.
In a perfect world it would work like this, I think.

```
<tg:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Uid="Table_Open" >
    <tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Uid="Button_Open" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenCustomerCommand}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
    </tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
</tg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This doesn't work, now I tried many opportunities but never reach the ViewModel.
I know in WPF it would work using

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},
```

But I don't get it reproduced in my UWP case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't use x:bind to bind `OpenCustomerCommand` in `DataTemplate`, In general, if we want to bind viewmodel's `OpenCustomerCommand` we need set current Page `DataContext` as `ViewModel` then use binding markup extension to bind like the following.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Margin="0,0,30,0" 
    Content="Favorite" 
    Command="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid,Path=DataContext.OpenCustomerCommand }" 
       />
```

And this is the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850757/uwp-button-click-from-listviewitem/60860411#60860411) case that your could refer.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it run. I definend current Page DataContext as ViewModel like this: <Page.DataContext>
    <customerViewModels:CustomerListViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

Comment: Please give root panel a x:name and binding ElementName="panel name".

Comment: I did, gave the Page, Grid, DataGrid an own x:Name and tried it with all. If i hit F12 on Path=DataContext.OpenCustomerCommand i reach the Command in CustomerListViewModel but in Debug its still without function, BreakPoints aren´t reached too. :((

Comment: @Keke, may be you need to insert the command into datasource please refer this case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61451757/7254781).

Comment: I realy don´t know how to figure it out. But got it run with ListView and your answers from other questions here on stackoverflow. Thanks for your help but can´t mark it as solved, i think there must be a way to get it run with DataGrid.

Comment: Yep, if the binding elementname can't work for datagrid, please try to move `OpenCustomerCommand` from viewmodel to each item. and it will works.