# Using other data binding context in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a following problem in my UWP project:

The data binding in DataGridTemplateColumn to another DataContext than for the row, doesn't work.

Here is my XAML structure:

```
<Page
        x:Name="Page1"
        x:Class="Project1.Class1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Project1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
        xmlns:tools="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls" xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="&lt;- Powrót" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="36" Foreground="#FF615E5A" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BackToMainPage" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="body">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Path:" />
                <TextBox x:Name="path" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Folder.Path}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Choose folder" Click="SelectFolder" />
    
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Name:" />
                <TextBox x:Name="file" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind FileName}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="X:"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="scope">
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="M" Tag="M"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="L" Tag="L"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="K" Tag="K" />
                </ComboBox>
    
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Code:"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="code" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Name:"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="name" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    
                <ListView Grid.Row="3" 
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                          x:Name="list" 
                          SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedSubmatrix, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubmatrixList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=body, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Name:"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Type:"></TextBlock>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="type" SelectedValue="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
                                        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="L" Tag="L"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="M" Tag="M"/>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="key" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=type, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="M">
                                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=key}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                                        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=type, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" Value="L">
                                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=key}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Key M:" />
                                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
                                        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="1" Tag="1"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="2" Tag="2"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="3" Tag="3"/>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </StackPanel>
    
                                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddColumnCommand}" />
                                <tools:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" RowHeight="200">
                                    <tools:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <tools:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
                                            <tools:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Page1, Path=DataContext.FileName}" />
                                                </DataTemplate>             
                                            </tools:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </tools:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <tools:DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        <!--<tools:DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa2" Binding="{Binding ElementName=Strona, Path=DataContext.FileName}" />-->
                                    </tools:DataGrid.Columns>
                                </tools:DataGrid>
                                <!--<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Strona, Path=DataContext.Dictionary2}" />-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
    
                <Button Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Add main" Click="AddSubmatrix"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Delete main" Click="DeleteSelectedSubmatrix"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Generate" Click="GenerateTemplate"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</Page>
```

Those three commented out lines were just for my testing and in all of them binding works properly, but for this uncommented one in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate -> DataTemplate doesn't. Does anybody knows why? And how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue for DataGrid, you can only access current item model's property  within `CellTemplate`. It will not work, if access root datacontext by elementname markup. For this scenario we suggest your add `FileName` into each item like this case [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61451757/7254781).

And the other way is intercepting DataGridTemplateColumn generate element method, and use new value to replace the old one.

For example, replace the `Name` property as the string "FileName"

```
 public class CustomDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
 {

     public CustomDataGridTemplateColumn()
     {
        
     }
     protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
     {
         (dataItem as Item).Name = "FileName";
         return base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
     } 
     public class Person
     {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public bool  IsMan { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Xaml Code

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Binding="{Binding Name}"
        Header="Rank"
        Tag="Rank"
        />
    <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Complete}"
        Header="Mountain"
        Tag="Mountain"
        />

    <local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn Header="Check" Tag="Test1">
        <local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{Binding Complete}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </local:CustomDataGridTemplateColumn>
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```